# Получение значения из ячейки html кликом по ячейке

Tags: javascript, html

Как можно получить данные из ячейки таблицы в буфер обмена, просто нажав на неё?

Таблица статичная.

Comment: А как выглядит эта таблица хотя-бы?

Comment: Можно абсолютно любую, банально 3 на 3 таблица.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте событие клик и берите значение из event target:

```js
let table = document.querySelector('table');
let output = document.querySelector('.output');

table.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
if(e.target.nodeName =="TD") {
 copyToClipboard (e.target.innerText)
}

})
let copyToClipboard = (str) => {
  let area = document.createElement('textarea');

  document.body.appendChild(area);  
area.value = str;
area.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
alert(`Скопированное значение ${area.value}`)
  document.body.removeChild(area);  
}
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Один</td>
    <td>Два</td>
    <td>Три</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>4413</td>
    <td>5мчс</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>аыв</td>
    <td>234234</td>
    <td>ииячис</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за наводку и решение

Comment: Хотя если не трудно,  могли бы вы показать как это переделать для копирования в буфер обмена?
Опыта не хватает, а так хоть на пример взгляну.

Comment: Добавил, смотрите. API буфера обмена, насколько я смотрю, лучше всего работает с полями input и textarea. И вообще на первый взгляд не очень удобное. В общем, как бы там ни было, выше код, выполняющий вашу задачу. Алерт можно убрать в любой момент.

Comment: Ох здравствуйте ещё раз и ещё раз спасибо, я впринципе потом к слову разобрался примерно, что вы имели ввиду и у меня получилось так(извиняюсь за нечитаемый вид).

`let table = document.querySelector('table');
let output = document.querySelector('.output');

table.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
if(e.target.nodeName =="TD") {
 navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.target.innerText);
 output.innerText = e.target.innerText
 
}

})`